# Генерация swagger yml в springfox

Tags: java, swagger

Как из springfox-swagger2 получить yml файл с описанием rest api?

Далее я хочу какой-нибудь библиотекой указать этот yml-файл и контроллер, и написать тест, который будет проверять соответствие фактического api к его yml-описанию